# When starting up an LDO, a spike appears on the output voltage; can it damage the microcontroller?

Tags: spike

(*This my first post, I hope you can clearly understand my problem*)

The ME6203-50 IC is a High Input Voltage LDO Regulators from Microne (Nanjing Micro One Electronics Inc).

I'm looking to use theses LDO for the small footprint and 100 mA output capacity to power small DIY uC 12F683 etc, from the datasheet Typical Application Circuit, it needs only 2 capacitors of 10 uF at the input and output.

But when connecting to my oscilloscope, I found out when applying 24 VDC or 12 VDC at the input, the output has a spike at the raise of the voltage before regulate to the preset value as mine 5 VDC.

I did connect a 0.01 uF, 0.1 uF, 1.0 uF at the input and output, and still the spike appears at startup.

From the datasheet on the scope test, there's no spike.

I wonder if this is normal, or in the long run can this spike damage the load as eg: uC 12F683 or other component.

As a reference I did the same test with a linear voltage regulator (78M05) and the startup as no spike at all, but I prefer to use the LDO as it dissipates less heat.

From the ME6203 datasheet 5) Line transient Response, there's no spike.

Here's is my oscilloscope tracking with and without load.

[image: ME6203-50 no load startup]

[image: ME6203-50 with load]

[image: ME6203 datasheet tracing]

[ME6203 Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6203A50PG_C94056.pdf)

Comment: Do you have the same source supply and same measuring setup for both regulators? Do you simply connect the regulator input with e.g. a switch to supply so there is a high inrush current and voltage step? How much there is load on the regulator?

Comment: yes I am using a regulated power supply, with a switch ON/OFF and the load is about 50mA

Comment: Also the test was done with a 78M05, same setup, without spike.

Comment: In the words of Hermes Conrad, "as this shocking graph indicates..." -- Your screenshot shows a one-pixel width line. That doesn't tell me it's a spike, or surge, or anything at all. Please zoom in until the rising edge and peak are resolved -- see the datasheet's example at 1ms/div (or even less may be needed).

Comment: Regulator flavor makes *no difference* to overall efficiency: you're still dropping from 12-24V down to 5V, at whatever the load current is.  An "HDO" or "LDO" does precisely the same effort. You can, however, consider a switching regulator, which can draw less input current than it outputs, and therefore dissipates less power.

Comment: Hi Tim , I did consider switching regulator like 2596, 4016, but the footprint to big

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Just to be clear, is the on/off switch (a) between the AC and the PSU or (b) between the PSU and the load (regulator circuit) ? If it's (a), it'd be unusual to get the spike you describe. If it's (b), that could be exacerbated by switch bounce. (Please can you always edit new info like this into your question, don't post it in comments, otherwise readers have to piece together the full question.)

Comment: _"I did consider switching regulator like 2596, 4016, but the footprint to big"_ - Did you factor a heat sink for the linear regulator into that comparison? 24->5V @100mA will dissipate 2W, it will need a heat sink.

Comment: @JackBerg What Tim is saying is that the 7805 is not less efficient than the ME6203. An LDO *can* use less power, because it can use a lower input voltage, but for the same input voltage you will get the same power dissipated either way. If you want a switching regulator, there are ones with much smaller footprints, especially if you need only 100 mA out. Consider for instance the MAX15062, in a tiny 2x2 mm package. Combine it with a tiny inductor like a coilcraft LPS3030, and you have a converter in a footprint much smaller than your ME6203 plus sufficiently-sized heatsink pad.

Comment: @Hearth 7805 has 4-8mA idle current and the LDO is in the tens of µA. So the LDO will be much more efficient on a low current load like a micro that spends most of its time sleeping. If the load is 100mA for a good length of time, a cheap readymade switching converter is a good choice (not the counterfeit ones).

Comment: I wonder if the spike is due to inductive coupling as the input cap charges, maybe due to probing. It should be examined at much faster scope sweep. For example if you have 10µF cap on the output, and you get 10V/µs spike, i=C dv/dt implies the LDO is outputting 100Amps, thats not gonna happen, so it's bad probing.

Comment: @bobflux That's true, but I didn't want to confuse matters while correcting a misunderstanding. It sounds like they think LDOs are just more efficient period, which is not true.

Answer (score 4):

The recommendation in the datasheet is for a tantalum capacitor. If you have substituted a ceramic capacitor you have probably compromised the stability, so having some overshoot would be a likely result.

I suggest you put a capacitor on the output of 22uF ceramic with about 1Ω in series and nothing else close to the regulator. Or a 10uF tantalum electrolytic rated for at least 3x the output voltage. The input can be a 10uF ceramic.

Answer (score 1):

This spike can be due to:

1. Capacitive coupling from input to output.
2. Inductive input return trace. If the load is wired directly across the output capacitor the spike may not cause a problem. RL1 in the circuit diagram will not see a spike but RL2 will. The same is true for an oscilloscope probe. When laying out a circuit, treat all traces as an inductor in series with a resistor that will create little voltage drops.
   Notice that spike current through C1 will be seen as a voltage spike to RL2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiH1gk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice in the datasheet Line Transient response, the input voltage rise time is close to 750μs. To me this means that the measured spike could be normal. For short input voltage rise times, it will be up to the designer to filter the input to increase the rise time of Vin.

A 3 to 15 ohm resistor in series with the input may be sufficient to eliminate the spike.

Comment: the 3 to 15 ohm resistor, is use as an de-coupling circuit I guess.

Comment: Let me add the input resistor, and see the result.

Comment: It forms a lowpass filter with the input capacitance thus slowing the rise time.  The resistor should be small as possible to reduce power consumption.

Comment: ok, let me try,

Comment: Hi, RussellH, did try with 4.7r, and 15r 1/4w, at the input, and still the same spike at the output, maybe  should use a 2596 smps instead.

Comment: for now I tossing this circuit a side, I'll look for another solution. thank's again RussellH

Comment: Thank's JYelton

Comment: time to log off, see back in few days

Answer (score 1):

Thank's Heart for the MAX15062, I downloaded the datasheet and looked at it.

I installed a zener at the output, that help reducing the spike to a normal level I think, the PIC12F683 as a Vcc 6.5V absolute max.

[image: ME6203 with zener]

[image: ME6203 without zener]

Comment: Putting a 4.47V zener after a 5V regulator may not be the best idea. It will draw extra current all the time, which of course makes the  regulator run hotter. At 24V input and 5V output, the zener may consume most current available from regulator and make it heat beyond specs. The resistor in series with the switch would have been a far better idea, as it would have limited the inrush current, rise time, and lower the voltage suitably down when regulator takes DC current.

Comment: you're right and I did some temperature reading and over an hour the result are 36 C degree max and the absolute max on the datasheet is 100C degree.

Comment: You're still wasting power. If you use a 5.1 V zener instead, you'll waste much less power, and it should still knock off the spike.

Comment: my order of 5.1v is in transit

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the PCB layout and probing setup are done correctly. Not a given, of course.

That's one rubbish LDO if it does that. Decent LDOs are designed to keep any transients on the output from exceeding the rated output voltage.

For 100mA from 12-24V, the good old 7805 is a safe way to go. No spikes. It needs to dissipate between 0.7W and 1.9W of heat, so the large package with a tab helps quite a bit. It should be heatsunk as well.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works, you can slow the rise of the regulator's input voltage with some series resistance prior to the regulator, R1 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8vU41.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 will drop about 1 V at full load (100mA), which isn't enough to cause the regulator to drop out.

The combination of R1 and C1 are a low-pass filter, which will slow the rising edge of input voltage, and that in turn should give the regulator more time to respond to any overshoot at the output.

Some LDO regulators don't like excessive input source impedance, but generally there would be something in the datasheet that addresses stability in such conditions. There's nothing about it in *this* datasheet though, so I presume it's not a problem.

Comment: Hello Simon, I'll try this today without the zener and make some reading

Comment: Tried with 100r resistor at the input, and the spike reading is at 7.2v.

Comment: I did adjust the DC input at 9.75V , and the're no spike at the output, any input voltage higher than 10v the spike come on at 7.2V

Comment: I guess this IC can work fine with an input voltage under 10V dc

Answer (score 0):

for Tim, here's 2 osc-graph 1: without zener 2: with zener
[ME6203 no zener at output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2KOL.jpg)
[image: ME6203 WITH ZENER]